# How to Reset Unifi APs over SSH?

Tags: ssh, unifi

I want to Reset APs or switches over the Build-in SSH. I do no find a working anser since [this](https://blog.rylander.io/2016/12/14/reset-a-unifi-ap-to-factory-settings-via-ssh/) is just turning the APs of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some time i found [this](https://support.hostifi.com/en/articles/6337741-unifi-how-to-factory-reset-an-access-point) article which had an expanded command on doing it.

For those who don´t need the whole explanation, the Command is as follows:

```
syswrapper.sh restore-default & set-default &
```